# If a string contains a double character change it to another string C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop

I created a Person Model:

```
Model Person = new Model();
Person.LastName = values[0];
```

*[LastName is a string]*
I would like to replace the **values [0]** which is "**Anna**" with another string value like "**Frank**" if it contains a double character, in this case "if **Anna** contains a **double character**, change the value
with another string".

*how to do?*

Comment: Simply repeating the same phrasing multiple times doesn't add much clarity to the question. For starters, *define* double character - is it the same character appearing twice in successive positions (e.g. the Ns in Anna) or is it the same character appearing twice *anywhere* in the string (e.g. the As in Anna, presuming case sensitivity isn't required, which is something *else* you should clarify in your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a helper function to test for consecutive equal characters:

```cs
private static bool HasDoubleCharacter(string s)
{
    char? previous = null;
    foreach (char ch in s) {
        if (ch == previous) {
            return true;
        }
        previous = ch;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The you can write

```cs
Model Person = new Model();
string name = values[0];
if (HasDoubleCharacter(name)) {
    name = "Frank";
}
Person.LastName = name;
```

You could also create a new array containing only names with no double character and use that one instead:

```cs
Model Person = new Model();
string[] names = values
    .Where(v => !HasDoubleCharacter(v))
    .ToArray();
if (names.Length > 0) {
    Person.LastName = names[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with easy extensions funciton for string:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool HasDoubleChar(this string @this)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(@this);

        for (int i = 1; i < @this.Length; i++)
        {
            if (@this[i] == @this[i - 1])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and then you could use it:

```
Person.LastName = values[0].HasDoubleChar()
    ? "Frank"
    : values[0];
```

Comment: Please, add `null` check (since you have `public` and more over *extension* method)

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as in *Michał Turczyn* post - a check for double character, but implemented via *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public static bool HasDoubleChar(string value) =>
  value != null && Regex.IsMatch(value, @"(.)\1");
```

pattern `(.)\1` explained:

```
(.) - group which contains an arbitrary character
\1  - the group #1 repeated again
```

Note, that we have some flexibility here: `(\p{L})\1` will check for double letters only, not, say, spaces; `(?i)(.)\1` will compare ignoring case (`Aaron` will be matched) etc.

then as usual

```
Person.LastName = HasDoubleChar(values[0])
    ? "Frank"
    : values[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        public static string Do(string source, string replacement)
        {
            char c = source.ToLower()[0]; // do you care about case? E.g., Aaron.
            for(int i = 1; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (source.ToLower()[i] == c)
                {
                    return replacement;
                }
            }
            return source;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            string thing = "Aaron";
            thing = Do(thing, "Frank");

        }
```

Comment: Voted down why?